# How do I solve the instantaneous rate at any given x?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

[image]

At number 3, I am given a world problem.
A and B are easy, you basically use the formula for average rate aka

> $\frac{y2-y1}{x2-x1}$

However, I am having a hard time solving instantaneous rates. ( my idea is on the picture) I understand the concept but am not sure how to apply it, especially the formula for it with the limit. I am taking Calc 1 this year and need help, please.

Comment: where is picture??

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Make sure to read through the help center, so that you know how to post an acceptable question!

Comment: do you know how to differentiate a function f(x) if yes then it should  be easy

Comment: $f'(x) = 15-2x$ is the instantaneous rate. You can compute it using the properties or using the definition of $f'(x)$.

Comment: Oh, I just have to use the derivative? Are instantaneous rates always derivative with the x value?

Comment: they are not always derivate with x value any other variable can also be used like you can find derivative of $sin(\theta)$ w.r.t. $\theta$

Answer (score 1):

The comment by Math lover above is correct. The definition of the instantaneous rate of change, the first derivative, is the limit
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + \Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}
$$
And here that is equal to $15-2x$. To calculate the derivative (the limit above), the derivative of a constant is zero and you can use the rule for each term of $x$ 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(ax^n) = nax^{n-1}
$$
you get $0 + 15x^0 -2x^1 = 15 -2x$